# Tornado server blocking script execution

Tags: python, server, raspberry-pi, tornado

I've got a python script that is supposed to start a tornado server and some other stuff. The problem is, whenever `tornado.ioLoop.IOLoop.current().start()` is executed, the running server blocks the entire script and my other stuff doesn't work. I'm new to tornado and fairly beginner at python so please excuse if this is common knowledge :)

Comment: You'll need to create multiple processes if your script does multiple things concurrently.  It`s  somewhat complex.  https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html. You might consider using supervisor to start your servers instead, which will handle starting to services and restarting on failure as well.

Comment: When you start the `IOLoop`, what it means is that Tornado actually enters a *forever running* loop. So, the code following that line will never run because the program is *stuck* in a loop. You've got two choices: (1.) Either start the `IOLoop` and the end of the script (2.) Or start it from a different script, or thread, or process.

Comment: @DanFarrell Thanks for your help, that worked! But I think I&#39;m not able to write websocket messages from the other process. Is that even possible?

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't be.